# lost library when recompiling Obj-C project

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa-bindings, libraries

When I recompiled an old Obj-C project (a Cocoa app), the linker couldn't find some common library modules, including sin() and sysctl().  This project had been working in the previous version of Xcode.  I am now using Xcode 3.1.2 in OSX 10.5.  The error message was:

```
Line Location Tool:0: collect2: ld returned 1 exit status  
Line Location Tool:0: symbol(s) not found  
Line Location Tool:0: _AmIBeingDebugged in MeterMileage.o  
Line Location Tool:0: "_sysctl", referenced from:  
Line Location Tool:0: -[AnimatedStar drawRect:] in AnimatedStar.o  
Line Location Tool:0: "_sin", referenced from:  
...
```

My current version of Xcode will link with the correct library for a new project using sin(), etc.  How do I fix the project which started in an earlier Xcode to use the correct library? I saw the post about linking in FFTW, but sin() is not so unusual, is it?

I suppose I could create a new project, and copy my code, etc into it, but that seems a little clumsy.  Is there a better way?  There will probably be more projects that need updating.

Thanks,
Gary

Comment: Did you clean the target and build results directory?

Comment: Yes - did "Clean all targets", deleted "Build" folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely that the older project is trying to explicitly link against an older copy of the C standard library or runtime that doesn't exist on 10.5.  Please post the linker *invocation* line, not just the error results; that should give us some clues.

Comment: Well, I had to do a little learning...  The closest I could find to a linker invocation line was the BUILD TRANSCRIPT line for GCC.  It had a "-nostdlib" flag.  Ah-hah!  That was the problem.  

Is there a way to see the actual linker invocation?  That might simplify things in the future by showing only the relevant ld flags (dropping the gcc stuff).  

Thank you for the help.